# How to run multiple cypress test cases in parallel in circle ci

Tags: cypress, circleci, parallel-testing

I am trying to run 60 Cypress test cases in parallel in circle Ci but it's running all the 60 test cases on all the 4 machines rather than dividing the test cases and running them in parallel in all the machines to reduce the time say 20 test cases in each machine,, i am stuck and deadline is just tomorrow please help me out

So far I am just able to run the same test cases in parallel in 4 machines but i want to split the test cases in 4 machines so the overy time should be reduced

Comment: Does this [Cypress parallel + CircleCI parllelism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71189822/16997707) answer your question?

Comment: No, I tried it but didn't work

Comment: Can you share your `cypress run` commands and probably share your circleci.yaml file as without having context, it's just hard to assist?

Comment: The behaviour you're describing suggests you're not properly splitting your tests. Check [the documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/use-the-circleci-cli-to-split-tests/).